# How To Negate Regex

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)
>   [How can I invert a regular expression in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538512/how-can-i-invert-a-regular-expression-in-javascript)

Say I have the regex `foo123`. How do I match everything that is **not** *foo123*?

Comment: The strings to match can have different lengths?

Comment: Sure. The actual pattern I'm trying not to match is: `^P[0-9]{1,}$`

Comment: Match as in search, or validation? For validation, you can use the same string, but use negation to the result of the matching function.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use negative lookahead for this.

```
(?!foo123).+
```

matches any string except `foo123`

If you want to match empty string also, use `(?!foo123).*`

In your case (according to the comment) the required regex is `(?!P[0-9]{1,}).+`.

It matches **P** and **123**, but not **P123**.

Comment: This is not going to work if you are searching in a file (none of them will work correctly when searching, but this is probably not what the OP wants). The first regex is also wrong for validation.

Comment: @nhahtdh how is it wrong?

Comment: I shouldn't have downvoted you since the question itself is confusing. Anyway, for matching: `(?!foo123).+` and `(?!foo123).*` http://www.regex101.com/r/gC0xA6 Add `^` and `$` for validation http://www.regex101.com/r/pS3zM5 Checking that the whole string does not follow the pattern can be done by using negation to result of match function instead of negating inside the regex

Comment: @nhahtdh So you mean `foo123khsdkfh` should not be matched and `afoo123khsdkfh` should be matched?

Comment: Since the OP is not very clear on what he wants (there are a number of ways to interpret the question), my downvote was a bit uncalled for (as I mentioned in my earlier comment). If you edit your answer a bit and clarify that the regex (surrounded with `^` and `$`) can only be used to validate that the whole string doesn't match the pattern, then I will remove the downvote.

Comment: I can't get the point in matching `afoo123khsdkfh` but not `foo123khsdkfh`

Comment: SEARCH: `\b(foo123)\b|.`  REPLACE BY: `(?{1}\1)`

Comment: @JustMe Didn't get your point.

Comment: match everything in text that is not "foo123" :) Maybe I didn't  understand the question??

Comment: @JustMe Why that replace part is there? OP just needs to find everything which is not  foo123.