# How to negate a regex only if the strings match exactly

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Before posting this question I have gone through the Regex Wiki and the following SO questions as well:

[How To Negate Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682905/how-to-negate-regex)

[How to exclude a specific string constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395177/regex-to-exclude-a-specific-string-constant)

Here is what I have gotten working, which is partially what I want:

```
(?!INVALID).*$
```

The first SO post actually solves my problem a little bit after editing the posted regex

The problem with what I have working is the regex fails when the word starts with `INVALID`

So basically :

- `TestINVALID` **will work**
- `TestINVALID123` **will work**
- `INVALID` will not match which is what I want so **will work**
- But `INVALIDTest` will not work, it **will not match**

I want the regex to not match only and only if string exactly matches "INVALID"

Comment: Please put details of your question directly into the question.

Comment: Isn't this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/how-to-negate-the-whole-regex

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can you either clearly state what you want to match, or just give examples of matching and non matching input?

Comment: Which flavor is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `$` in your negative look ahead:

```
^(?!INVALID$).*
           ^----------added "$" here
```

This prevents *the entire input* (not just the *leading* input) from being `"ÌNVALID"`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a **tempered greedy token**:

```
^(?:(?!INVALID).)+$
```

This invalidates all of the following but the last:

```
TestINVALID
TestINVALID123
INVALID
INVALIDTest
this one will be valid
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gV9pR0/1) and mind the `multiline` flag.

---

Having read you question again, it has gotten unclearer. Do you want to match lines where there is only the word `INVALID` in it? This can be achieved with simple string functions **or** (if you insist on using regular expressions):

```
^INVALID$ # look for INVALID from start to end of the line
```

See [**a demo for this one on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gV9pR0/2) as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying out the regex, and I apologize if the question was a bit unclear. Actually the requirement itself was a bit confusing so not sure if I phrased it well. Again, appreciate it.