# negative lookaround catches nothing

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I've come across a number of [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682905/how-to-negate-regex) on the interwebs showing that if you want to negate an entire regex pattern you can just embed it inside:
(?! pattern here )

But instead it catches on nothing for me. I've tried it on a number of [sites](https://regex101.com/#javascript) and apps that use regex, but no dice. Here's an example.

Suppose I have these strings:

> strangecowfeet
>
> mycow
>
> yourcow
>
> hiddendonkey
>
> cowfishyummy

This pattern matches all except hiddendonkey:

```
cow
```

But then If I do:

```
(?!cow)
```

It doesn't match on anything. I've tried a bunch of variants I've seen around (trailing .* and .+ and spaces and anchors, etc), but to no avail.

Looks like I've overlooking a very basic flaw.

Comment: It is called a lookaround, a zero-width assertion, because it does not *consume* (=return) any text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word explains how to use the lookahead inside a tempered greedy token, and much more.

Comment: Just use `^(?!.*cow).*$` and be done with it.