# negated lookahead confusion

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match strings that do *not* fit the pattern `name (CA)` or `barbaz (UK)`. I seem to have solved the problem using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1538524/1898641), but this is what I started with, and I'm wondering why it doesn't work:

```
var r1 = /^.+(?!\([A-Z]{2}\))$/;

r1.test('foo'); //true

r1.test('foo (US)'); //whoops -also true
```

From reading a negated lookahead [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead) I was hoping that any string that is not followed by e.g. `(JP)` would result in a match, while anything that *is* followed by e.g. `(DE)` would fail. (Only the former is being met).

I thought perhaps the `.+` was kind of "consuming" everything, nullifying the lookahead, so I tried

```
r2 = /^[^()]+(?!\([A-Z]+\))$/;

r2.test('name (US)'); //false

r2.test('foo('); //whoops -also false
```

However I need things like `foo(` to match.

Why did my first attempt fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first expression, the `.+` consumes the whole string and then the look-ahead is tested - it doesn't match, as there are no characters left. To achieve your goal you can use `/^(?!.+\([A-Z]{2}\)$).+$/` - first checking the non-presence of the unwanted construct, then matching.

See https://regex101.com/r/aG7xZ0/1 with your samples

Comment: Thanks for the link. Could you elaborate how you used $ ?

Comment: It is simply used to ensure, that `(XX)` is only matched at the end of the string, and not somewhere in the middle, so `Hello (XX) World` would be valid.

Comment: Cool I think that covers the one inside the lookahead, but then there's `.+$` at the end?

Comment: Simply matching everything up to the end - though you could drop the `$`, as `+` matches lazy anyways.

Comment: given that anything placed after `(XX)` should result in `true`, I'm confused by the final `.+` -sorry I'm rubbish!

Comment: The look-ahead doesn't match anything itself, so you need the `.+` for actual matching.

Comment: For when you use `exec` rather than `test` and want to see matched text?

Comment: According to your question you wanted to match strings - if you only want to test you could also `! /\([A-Z]{2}\)$/.test('whatever')`

Comment: sorry yes see what you mean. Thanks

Comment: do need to match :)